# How to unit test MediatR method that returns Unit.Value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mediatr

How do you unit test a MediatR method returning Unit.Value?
I never understood what Unit.Value stands for, either, in MediatR.
Does it mean it returns false in case of error and true in every other instance? So in this case a way to unit test would be to make sure no errors (mock dependencies etc), and just check if result in the shape of Unit.Value equals true?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unit is a type with a single value. You can think of it as void, except is a regular type and not a keyword.

You should test the method like any method that returns void: Verify that it has the desired side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `Unit` as `void`  - returns nothing.

(Note: newer versions of Mediatr wrap this up so you can just return `Task`)

But for example purposes, suppose you have a `Handler` like this

```
public class MyHandler : IRequestHandler<Unit>
{
    public MyHandler(IDoSomething doSomething)
    {
        _doSomething = doSomething;
    }

    public Task Handle(MyRequest req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _doSomething.Do();

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

Your tests can mock your dependency, and assert it was called:

```
public class MyHandlerTests
{
    private Mock<IDoSomething> _doSomethingMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _doSomethingMock = new Mock<IDoSomething>();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Calls_DoSomething()
    {
        // Arrange
        var handler = new MyHandler(_doSomethingMock.Object);

        // Act
        await handler.Handle(new MyRequest(), CancellationToken.None);

        // Assert
        _doSomethingMock.Verify(x => x.Do(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use auto-fixture for mocking and generating Data,I hope use it and enjoying with write automate test

Comment: var Fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization()
        {
            ConfigureMembers = true
        }).Customize(new SupportMutableValueTypesCustomization());
        
        Mediator = Fixture.Create<IMediator>();

Comment: Is the comment meant to be additional information for your answer? If so you should edit and update your answer not add as a comment with no supporting connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).